# Tables are empty in Query Builder when Saved SQL script is retrieved

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, query-builder

I saved a query I created in the SQL Developer Query Builder.
When I retrieved the query, the linked Tables don't show the Column Names in the Query Builder.

The Tables are still linked/joined to one another and the query still runs, but the columns names are blank.

How do I get the Column Name to reappear?

I'm new to SQL Developer, so I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Empty Columns in Query Builder]

Searched through the menus for something that would restore the columns names.
Searched through help option on SQL Developers and nothing found relating to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was very tempted to delete this post when I found the answer myself.
However, I think there are more rookies out there like me.

The resolution is to add a semi-colon ";" to the end of the statement in the Worksheet Tab.

Even though I created the query in the Query Builder Tab, SQL Developer creates the SQL Statement in the Worksheet Tab.

So for some reason after you save that Query that was created in the Query Builder Tab; when you retrieve the script, you must add ";" to the end of the SQL Statement in the Worksheet Tab or else you get the issue I encountered with the blank columns.